# How to login by POST method to get access the other APIs from Server Android

Tags: android, authentication, http-post, httpclient, httpurlconnection

In my app I want to to implement a login functionality to get access to server for getting all the necessary API colection. The login request will send by POST method. For login,  email address is the mandatory field and password is optional. If I authenticate with the email address, I am able to get all the api colection from server like "/api/users", "api/image". Also the app will redirect to next page. I have tried with the following code to authenticate from server by POSt method. But nothing happen with code. Neither I get any respnse from server nor I redirect to next page. It seems that I have some problem in my code. But I fail to resolve what exactly the problem is.

**Here I would like to mention that I do not want to use any library for url connection**

Here is my code for login page

```
    public class LoginPage extends AppCompatActivity {


    private UserLoginTask mAuthTask = null;

    EditText userEmail;
    EditText userPassword;
    TextView forgotPassword;
    View progressView;
    View loginFormView;
    Button login;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_layout);

        //Set up the login form
        userEmail=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        userPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        forgotPassword=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.forgot_password);
        forgotPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Redirect to forgot password link",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        userPassword.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (id == R.id.password || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                    attemptLogin();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                attemptLogin();
            }
        });

        loginFormView = findViewById(R.id.login_form);
        progressView = findViewById(R.id.login_progress);

    }

    /**
     * Attempts to sign in or register the account specified by the login form.
     * If there are form errors (invalid email, missing fields, etc.), the
     * errors are presented and no actual login attempt is made.
     */
    private void attemptLogin() {
        if (mAuthTask != null) {
            return;
        }

        // Reset errors.
        userEmail.setError(null);
        userPassword.setError(null);

        String email = userEmail.getText().toString();
        String password = userPassword.getText().toString();

        boolean cancel = false;
        View focusView = null;

        // Check for a valid password, if the user entered one.
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(password) && !isPasswordValid(password)) {
            userPassword.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));
            focusView = userPassword;
            cancel = true;
        }
        else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
            userPassword.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
            focusView = userPassword;
            cancel = true;
        }

        // Check for a valid email address.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            userEmail.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
            focusView = userEmail;
            cancel = true;
        } else if (!isEmailValid(email)) {
            userEmail.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
            focusView = userEmail;
            cancel = true;
        }
        if (cancel) {
            // There was an error; don't attempt login and focus the first
            // form field with an error.
            focusView.requestFocus();
        } else {
            // Show a progress spinner, and kick off a background task to
            // perform the user login attempt.
            showProgress(true);
            mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask(email, password,this);
            mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);
        }

    }
    private boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
        //TODO: Replace this with other logic
        Pattern pattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS;
        return pattern.matcher(email).matches();
        //return true;
    }

    private boolean isPasswordValid(String password) {
        //TODO: Replace this with your own logic
        return password.length() > 4;
    }

    /**
     * Shows the progress UI and hides the login form.
     */
   @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
    private void showProgress(final boolean show) {
        // On Honeycomb MR2 we have the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs, which allow
        // for very easy animations. If available, use these APIs to fade-in
        // the progress spinner.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
            int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

            loginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            loginFormView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                    show ? 0 : 1).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    loginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
            progressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            progressView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                    show ? 1 : 0).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    progressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                }
            });
        } else {
            // The ViewPropertyAnimator APIs are not available, so simply show
            // and hide the relevant UI components.
            progressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            loginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    private interface ProfileQuery {
        String[] PROJECTION = {
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.IS_PRIMARY,
        };

        int ADDRESS = 0;
        int IS_PRIMARY = 1;
    }

    /**
     * Represents an asynchronous login/registration task used to authenticate
     * the user.
     */
    public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        private final String mEmail;
        private final String mPassword;
        Activity instance;

        UserLoginTask(String email, String password,Activity instance) {
            mEmail = email;
            mPassword = password;
            this.instance=instance;
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.

            JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
            try {
                request.put("email",mEmail );
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                request.put("pass",mPassword );
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String result =  connectWithServer(instance , request,mEmail,mPassword);

            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(result)){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
            mAuthTask = null;
            showProgress(true);
            if (success) {
                finish();
                Intent loginIntent = new Intent(LoginPage.this, MainOptionPage.class);
                startActivity(loginIntent);
            } else {
                userEmail.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
                userPassword.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            mAuthTask = null;
            showProgress(false);

        }
    }
    public static String connectWithServer(Activity ctx , JSONObject request, String username, String password) {
        String result ="";
        try {
            //Connect
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL("https://myurl/login")).openConnection());
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.connect();
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(100000);

            //Write
            OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

            writer.write(request.toString());
            writer.close();
            outputStream.close();

            //Read
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            String line;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            result = sb.toString();
            Toast.makeText(ctx,result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the problem, but It think it's a bit weird that you close the writer before reading, maybe it closes the connection ?

Comment: @JesseHoobergs Could you plaese explain me in my code, how to resolve this.

Comment: In connectWithServer move the writer.close() and outputStream.close() to bufferedReader.close()